# How to get span to be only as wide as the image inside of it?

Tags: css, image, firefox, xhtml

I have a span wrapping a img element and another span element, which is used for the description of the image. I want the image to be on top and then some text below the image.
I found a way using firefox specific css properties, but this wont work on any other browser. Is there another way to get this effect or mimic how it looks in firefox?

HTML:

```
 <span class="image">
   <img class="" alt="pic" src="pic.jpg" />
     <span class="img-desc">
       Call us today!
       <span>888-888-8888</span>
     </span>
  </span>
```

CSS:

```
 .image {
    float: right;
    width: -moz-min-content;
}
```

Comment: A span by default will only expand to the width of its content. Are there some other styles being applied that is altering default behaviors?

Comment: Sparky you have the best and most simple answer. Thanks

Comment: No @animuson, that is all that is applied to those elements

Comment: @Sparky672: Using a division will not solve anything, floating a division or a span to the right produce essentially the same exact result.

Comment: @animuson to be fair sparky is right. here is the example that was suggested http://jsfiddle.net/2KANB/1/

Comment: @Nils R: That doesn't use a division...

Comment: He said use <div>s i dont know what this division is. I am just assuming he meant to replace all spans with divs

Comment: @animuson, I said `<div>`'s and [he changed his `<span>`'s to `<div>`'s](http://jsfiddle.net/2KANB/1/)... what's the confusion here?

Comment: @Sparky672: I was just saying that floating a division and span to the right *produce the **exact** same result* so I was confused why he was changing them in the first place because it makes no sense. Nils R: 'div' is short for 'division', just FYI. But I understand now that he meant the inner parts.

Comment: **Quote:** _"Sparky you have the best and most simple answer."_  **-** I've since posted my simple answer below along with an explanation about why `<div>`'s and `<span>`'s give you different results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change all of your `<span>`'s into `<div>`'s and it will work.  That's because, by default, a `<div>` (block level) will cause line-breaks before & after itself, where a `<span>` (inline) does not.

http://jsfiddle.net/TbY4N/

`<span>`'s were designed for "inline" use and, generally, you shouldn't see them containing a bunch of other tags or block level elements.  Although, you can easily force them to behave like `<div>`'s (block level), this is an issue of proper semantics.

[Span versus Div according to the W3C wiki article...](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Generic_containers_-_the_div_and_span_elements)

> "The **div** element, short for division, is the *block level* generic
>   container. **It is normally used to wrap around other block level
>   elements**, to group them together (see the next section for more of
>   an exploration of this). It can also be used to collect together a
>   bunch of inline elements and/or text that otherwise don’t logically
>   fit under another block level element, but this should be a last
>   resort."
>
> "The **span** element is the *inline level* generic container. It also
>   helps to inform the structure of document, but **it is used to group
>   or wrap other inline elements and/or text, rather than block level
>   elements.**"

Answer (score 1):

```
<span class="image">
 <img class="" alt="pic" src="pic.jpg" />
  <br />
  <span class="img-desc">
   Call us today!
   <br />
   <span>888-888-8888</span>
  </span>
</span>
```

Comment: sure, but a couple of line breaks never harmed anyone :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with css by clearing the image element.
Once the image is cleared you can float the .img-desc (either left or right) which will be placed under the image.  This should work for any width of image. In my example I've just used a default image making it 50px wide.

http://jsfiddle.net/2KANB/